# Troublshooting performance issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have two tables - `Things` and `History`. Let's say `Things` have a column `Id` as primary key and another column `LastUpdated` that is some kind of timestamp value. There is an index on `LastUpdated` column. There are other columns but I believe that should not be of much relevance. I have two business workflows from my ASP.NET MVC Web API application

1. Gets things that are changed since last time. Runs a query of form: `SELECT [Columns] FROM Things WHERE LastUpdated > @LastUpdated`. This query is fired on connection w/o transaction or transaction scope.
2. Updates particular thing. This happens in two database transactions - first transaction has a `SELECT` on `Things` with `Id` followed by `UPDATE Things` using `Id`. The second transaction inserts row in `History` table. Both transactions are controlled using `TransactionScope` with `Read Committed` isolation level.

I am trying to bench mark the performance with a scenario such as

- 5000 rows in `Things` table
- 25 queries (#1 above) per second
- 200 updates (#2 above) per second

Environment: My dev machine (Core i7, 8GB) with Sql Server 2016 LocalDB engine.

What I am observing is that as the number of rows increases in `History` table, performance degrades for both #1 and #2. #2 is understandable as it actually updates the history table. However, I am puzzled that why #1 gets degraded dramatically. For example, #2 time degrades from around 10 ms at empty database to around 65 ms for 250K rows in `history` table while #1 time degrades from around 10 ms to 200 ms. Note that `Things` table have constant number of rows (5000). Only explanation that I can think of is due to contention at Disk IO.

Am I right here? Is there any way to verify this(say, using SQL Profiler)?

Comment: Is `History` table only ever inserted into or do you update history table as well? Do you ever `SELECT` from History table? What is the data type of a column(s) that gets updated in "Thing"? What indexes do you have?

Comment: What type of index do you have on LastUpdated column?

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler to capture queries as well as durations, you can also use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan to see what plans are used.

Comment: even if you think you have 8Gb, your Sql Server 2016 LocalDB can use only 1Gb as it's a feature of SQL Server Express that is limited to 1Gb. If your data cannot fit into memory it'll be constantly read from disk, that is the slowest thing. P.S. volumes of data are mesured not in "number of rows" but in Mb/Gb.

Comment: @Alex, there is only insert into History table. No select for this scenario. Thing has nvarchar(max) column and 2-3 bit columns - typical data size in this scenario is around 600 characters (1200 bytes).

Comment: @Jaques, LastUpdated has non-clustered index while primary key has clustered index

Comment: @sepupic, point noted. However, I am not exactly looking at *actual* number but rather behavior under increasing load. What puzzling me is that why increasing number of rows in History table affects #1 query so much when it does not actually access that table at all?

Comment: Assuming that you have 250K rows in history, can you run `ALTER INDEX PK_indexname ON Thing REORGANIZE` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql), then re-run your tests. On second thought do an index re-build.

Comment: >>>What puzzling me is that why increasing number of rows in History table affects #1 query so much<<< because the data cache is one for all your queries. So even if your Things table data is not changed, it can be just aged out of the cache, an it means the next time you are going to read it, it should be read from disk and not from cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't spend as much time as to my liking on this but as suspected, the apparent reason seams to be disk I/O contention. I moved the history table to another database on different machine. And now, number of rows in history table stopped affecting #1 timing, it remains more or less constant (6-7% variance) irrespective of number of rows in history table.